# Filter list, only unique values - with python

Tags: python, filter

I was wondering how I would take a list, ex a = [1, 5, 2, 5, 1], and have it filter out unique values, so that it only returns a number that only occurred once in the list. So it would give me a=[2] as a result.

I was able to figure out how to filter out duplicates, now how would I get rid of the duplicates?

No need for the straight answer, just a little tip or hint is welcome :)

I was able to find this on stackoverflow. It does what I want, but I do not understand the code though, can someone break it down for me?

```
d = {}
for i in l: d[i] = d.has_key(i)

[k for k in d.keys() if not d[k]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> a = [1, 5, 2, 5, 1]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> [k for k, c in Counter(a).iteritems() if c == 1]
[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hear is what your code does:

```
d = {}
for i in list:
    # if the item is already in the dictionary then map it to True,
    # otherwise map it to False 
    # the first time a given item is seen it will be assigned False,
    # the next time True
    d[i] = d.has_key(i)

# pull out all the keys in the dictionary that are equal to False
# these are items in the original list that were only seen once in the loop
[k for k in d.keys() if not d[k]]
```